# I can't access my raspi camera with my raspberry pi 3 B+

Tags: terminal, camera

I am currently trying to start my Raspberry Pi V2.1 camera with my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ but I couldn't accomplish it. It may be because of the ribbon-cable since my cable for the camera is narrower, thus I believe that it is for the Raspberry Pi Zero. Can't I use the Raspberry Pi Zero's camera ribbon cable for Raspberry Pi 3?

When I try the command: `vcgencmd get_camera`b, the output is: `supported=1 and detected=0`. And when I try the command: `raspistill -o output.jpg`, the output is:

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

Do you believe the problem is because of the ribbon cable that is used for Raspberry Pi Zero or do you think there is a software problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the same cable for both Raspberry Pi Zero and Pi 3+. Both of them support different set of cameras and are not interchangeable. You can always use USB camera interchangeably on them though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to change the cable.

Comment: `Both of them support different set of cameras and are not interchangeable` not correct. All Pi models can use all Pi camera modules. And both type of cables can be used with all Pi camera models  The only issue here is that you need a different cable for Pi Zero (W) models.Just get another cable and swap the cable on the camera side instead of the Pi side.

Comment: Agreed. I tried it on both and it didn't work so I came to this conclusion. But officially, it is mentioned that only cables are different. Excerpt from Arrow : "It is also good to know that camera inputs can be added to both SBCs. If you are using the official Raspberry Pi camera modules, they can be adapted to be used by simply switching the ribbon camera cables. The original cable that comes with the camera modules can be easily used on the RP3, but to use it for the RPZW, you’ll need to get the Raspberry Pi Zero v1.3 Camera Cable since the original cable is too large for the RPZW."